# Android using Java won't display image using picasa dependence

Tags: java, android

## Line of code in java codes to retrieve image path

```
jsonObject.getString("image"); // this is the path
```

### My JSON file

````
  "image":"/Users/jz/Desktop/RwandanMeal/Omellete.jpg"
} ```

## Result in logcat

``` {
 "image":"\/Users\/jz\/Desktop\/RwandanMeal\/ugari.jpg"
} ```

As you see my path has been manipulated and it could be the reason
````

Answer (score 1):

Remove backslashes

```
jsonObject.getString("image").replace("\\","");
```

Comment: This line works        Picasso.with(context).load("https://www.examplewebsite.com/image.jpg").into(holder.imageView);
this line doesnot work         Picasso.with(context).load("localpath/image.jpg").into(holder.imageView);
and I want to display images from my computer storage, How can I do that with Picasso